# adding onclick event to dynamically generated array of element jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamically generated thumbnail images on the left side of my popup and on click of the image i want that image to be displayed on the right hand side.

I am using the below code:

```
    $.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",
                    url:  "/buildyourholiday/placeimages",
                    data: "srcid="+cityid,
                    success: function(data){
                        var objsrc = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                        var src="";
                        $(".photoright").append().empty();
                        $.each(objsrc, function(index, obsrc){
                            src += '<ul>'+
                                '<li><a href="#"><img id="citythumb" onclick="sliderimage(this)" src="/images/city/thumbs/'+obsrc.img_filename+'" width="100" height="100"></a></li>'+
                                '</ul>';
                        });
                        $(".photoright").append(src);
                        function sliderimage(image)
{
    alert("sdf");
    alert(image);
}
                    }
                });
```

When i firebug it i get sliderimage is not a function. When i use the onclick event after append i get only the first image, but there are multiple images. I want the onclick to work on the click of any image. How to go about it?

Thanks,

Comment: please make alert using parameter of sliderimage function and tell whether it works for all images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id="citythumb"` must be unique, use `class`, like `class="citythumb"`

```
$(".photoright").on('click', 'img', function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); // for link
   alert(this);
});
```

when you change `id` attribute, you could also replace `img` with `.citythumb`

Answer (score 0):

Try event delegation approach here where in the events are associated to the elements ancestor ..

By doing so because of bubbling effect the click event will be associated to the image element in such cases...

```
$(".photoright").on('click', 'img', function(){
   alert(this);
});
```

Make sure the id in your document is unique.

So instead of **id="citythumb"**  declare **class="citythumb"**

Answer (score 0):

Please move the sliderimage() function outside of Ajax call

```
 $.ajax({  
 });

 function sliderimage(image){     
   alert("sdf");
   alert(image);
 }
```